# How to use Extensible Choice Parameter in Jenkins DSL to create pipeline jobs from a list?

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I am quite new to Jenkins, so any help understanding coding practice and jargon would be appreciated.

I am trying to create a Jenkins DSL job that will create several other pipeline jobs from a list. I am having trouble setting up the Extensible Choice Parameter in the created-jobs.

```
<snipped code>
def jobs = [
    [
        name: "job1",
        scriptPath: "folder/path/script1",
        choiceList: "one,two,three"
    ],
    [
        name: "job2",
        scriptPath: "folder/path/script2",
        choiceList: "adam,boy,charlie"
    ]

for ( job in jobs) {
    def name = job[name]
    def scriptPath = job[ScriptPath]
    def choiceList = job[choiceList]

    pipelineJob("${name}) {
        displayName(name)

        parameters{
            extensibleChoice(
                description: 'The Job Description',
                multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                name: name,
                quoteValue: false,
                saveJSONParameterToFile: false,
                type:PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                value: choiceList,
                visibleItemCount: 100
            )
        }
        <snipped code>
    }
}
```

error message:
No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.extensibleChoice() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap)

My thoughts are that I am using the wrong function call, but I am not quite sure where to confirm I have the right caller. I have tried looking for examples, but I have not found any on the plugin page/wiki or with my internet searches.